# Can't get Ubuntu to use two NICs at the same time on different networks

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, nic

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and am having a hard time getting both NICs to work at the same time on different networks.

I have network 1 that connects to the internet and network 2 that connects to a NAS and other resources.

Each one works individually if I disconnect the other one. But they dont work at the same time. I tried some of the suggestions in other older threads like making sure they dont have the same subnets and making sure only one has a default gateway, and their ips are not in the same range as far as I can tell. I also made sure they are using different MAC addresses just in case

when one stops working it really stops, like on the router it doesnt show the device anymore if that helps.

I am not sure how to share ifconfig or route safely without exposing my ip to ddos or mac addresses for security on the network but if someone walks me through that can share what i need to help you help me =)

what i think i need to do is set them as static ips, seperate netmasks, only one with default gateway. I just cant seem to accomplish this (or verify I have accomplished this) through the GUI. help to do it through command line would be fantastic.

i did see some older threads about this topic, but they are from Ubuntu 12 and 14 and when I tried to follow along with the working solutions the files they wanted me to edit didnt exist =(

** ADDED INFORMATION FROM QUESTIONS / thanks to @chili555 for showing best practices to stay safe

ifconfig when both are connected but only network 1 works:

```
eno8303: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.x.y  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 10.10.a.b
        inet6 fe80::9b5a:98e3:XXXX:XXXX  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:Xc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 49005255  bytes 9779685701 (9.7 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17858283  bytes 3889222415 (3.8 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 48  

eno8403: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:Xd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2107226  bytes 800274299 (800.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 67827  bytes 8155445 (8.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 134
```

netplan is just NetworkManager, maybe thats where i need to make changes. here is my yaml:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

route

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno8303
10.10.x.y       0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     100    0        0 eno8303
10.244.x.y      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 zeroTeir
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eno8303
172.17.x.y      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.x.y      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br
```

SOLVED by Rinzwind in the comments , this link for netplan was what I needed --> https://serverfault.com/questions/939922/netplan-with-2-nics-each-connected-to-a-different-gateway/949447#949447

I dont know how to flag this question as solved , but it is.

Comment: Show the networking configurations you've tried in Netplan so far.  Note that you are using Netplan if you are on 20.04, and older 12.04 and 14.04 solutions won't work for Netplan managed systems.  We need to see examples of how you've tried configuring these systems first, otherwise we won't be able to ID your failed network configs.  Otherwise, we can only provide example configuration files that you would have to adapt for your system.

Comment: I don't see any security risk in showing your MAC addresses, nor your IP addresses provided they are from one of the private IPv4 address ranges. As it stands, your question provides too little information to even guess at possible causes of your problem, so I can only recommend you read up about netplan.

Comment: thanks to you both for replying. My concern about the MAC addresses is that my work whitelists MAC addresses on the network for security. While I take my devices home and work on them in a private setting, publicly sharing the MAC addresses could expose my work network to a security breach as MAC spoofing is super easy in that its a feature of a NIC.

I am a ubuntu network n00b so I have been doing all this in NetworkManager , my netplan is essentially:

`# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
`
im guessing not helpful?

Comment: Read `man ip-route`.

Comment: "I am not sure how to share ifconfig or route safely" Like this: 192.168.x.y. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks @chili555 for both the advice and the welcome! I have added `ifconfig` , `route` , and my yaml for `netplan` to the original post now

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/962016/netplan-config-for-two-network-interfaces#:~:text=https%3A//askubuntu.com/a/962085/15811 has an example. Looks like that might work (not sure as the last time I had 2 nics on one system is more than 20 years ago so my knowledge is rusty on this) Here is another one: https://serverfault.com/a/949447/229730 but a bit more intricate

Comment: thanks @Rinzwind will try this now and report back if it works or not

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks that worked! much appreciated!

Comment: @LabCoatNomand cool! do make an answer from what you did to get it working and accept your answer. that will clear this q from the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Rinzwind and others the solution was to make a custom netplan (https://netplan.io/), while I did end up adding some custom settings specific to my environment, this the basis that got me going to talk to both networks separately:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
   eno8303:
    dhcp4: yes
    nameservers:
        search: [foo.local, bar.local]
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
   eno8403:
    dhcp4: yes
```